# Выборка на Laravel из бд

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel, backend

Надо сделать выборку из бд, и перебрав содержимое - вывести.

```
public function show($id)
{
    $tables = DB::table('INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES')->select('TABLE_NAME')
        ->where('TABLE_SCHEMA', $id)->get()->toArray();

    foreach ($tables as $table) {
        echo $table;
    }
}
```

Но пишет ошыбку:

> Error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in file

Comment: эта проблема решается самостоятельно примерно за 5 секунд. Как вы считаете, что у вас в $table?

Comment: Скорее всего, тупо нет доступа к таблице.
Попробуй простую команду `SHOW TABLES`